# question about Inconvertible types cannot cast

Tags: java

Compiler gives error: Inconvertible types cannot cast

```
String s = "aa";
Integer i = (Integer)s;
```

But for below code,

```
class A implements Runnable{
    @Override
    public void run() {
    }
}
class B extends A implements Observer {
    @Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
    }
}
```

When trying to use, why there is no compilation error? A is not related to Observer at all.

```
   A a = new A() ;
   Observer ob = (Observer) a ; //compile OK but runtime fail
```

Comment: If I changed your line to `A a = new B();`, we wouldn't expect an error (runtime or otherwise) anymore. In this sense, the compiler doesn't really care to check the casts, as something could come along and extend the functionality to make the cast valid. In your case, you're comparing a `final class String` to `class A`: The `final`ity of the class actually matters! If you marked `A` as `final` (removing `B` in the meantime), then your example becomes a compiler error.